# htaccess rule of http_cookies not following condition

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

When I hit the URL without login it will redirect to the login page - which is okay.

But after login when I hit the same URL then also it will redirect to the dashboard page.

As it is following the same condition for that particular URL only which I open before log in. Once I logged In and open the https://www.doamin.com/folder1/folder2/?uu then also it open why this happening.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder1/folder2 [NC]
RewriteRule . https://www.doamin.com/account/?redirect_too=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```